# Twitter client with JQuery not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, twitter, jsonp

I've got a little script that fetches my latest tweets. I use JQuery's `$.getJSON()` method to fetch my tweets.

The script works well with Chrome and Safari but when it comes to Firefox, nothing appears!

Here's the code:

```
var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=lpdahito&count=3&callback=?';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $('#tweets').html('<p>' + 
        data[0].text + '</p><p>' + 
        data[1].text + '</p><p>' + 
        data[2].text + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: works fine for me in ff3.6.3. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: Does it append the html properly? I can fetch the JSON object... I'm just not able to make it's content appear on my page using firefox... It works great with Chrome and Safari though.
If I use the "alert" function instead of "html" I see my content.

Answer (score 1):

It works well using Firefox 3.6 mac. You can always add :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

before your JSONP call to try to figure out what's wrong. But nothing's wrong here.

Comment: Thx for answering...
When you say nothing's wrong, did you see the tweets appear?
I get the JSON object in FF, it just won't show in my html...
Whereas with Chrome or Safari, it'll show.

Comment: Yep, it appeared. I'm sorry I can't help you more, you should give more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to tell Firefox when to call the script.

I added:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //my code here
});
```

Everything is fine now.